# IIS Advanced Logging - how to quote cs-uri-stem field

Tags: iis, logging, iis-advanced-logging

The cs-uri-stem field is not enclosed in double quotes and sometimes has spaces in it.  The other fields such as cs(User-Agent), cs(Cookie) are enclosed in double quotes.

With the cs-uri-stem field containing spaces and not enclosed in double quotes, it is causing some problems with our parsing routines to know when the cs-uri-stem ends and the next field starts.

I would know if in your experience there is a way to solve this problem.

By now the best solution I can think is have the cs-uri-stem as last field of the sequence:

```
date-local time-local cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) cs-uri-stem
```

So I can take as 5th field the rest of line.